# Understanding a Linked List implementation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, linked-list

I have found an implementation of a Linked List in Python, online, but it doesn't have any explanation or comments.

I understand the underlying concepts of a Linked List, but there is one key part of the code I don't understand:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def set_next(self, next):
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head == None

    def add(self, item):
        temp = Node(item)
        temp.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = temp

    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0

        while current != None:
            count += 1
            current = current.get_next()

        return count

    def search(self, item):
        current  = self.head

        while current != None:
            if current.get_data() == item:
                return True
            else:
                current = current.get_next()

        return False

    def remove(self, item):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        found = False

        while not found:
            if current.get_data() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.get_next()

        if previous == None:
            self.head = current.get_next()
        else:
            previous.set_next(current.get_next())
```

I don't understand how the `size`, `search` and `remove` methods in the `LinkedList` class are able to call functions from the `Node` class via the `current` variable, after setting it to `self.head`, which seems to be contained within the scope of the `LinkedList` class.

Is it because the `add` method sets `self.head = temp`, where `temp` is a Node object?

If possible, could someone explain how this works?

Comment: Yes. `current` is set to `self.head` which is a `Node` object (and subsequently, to *other* `Node` objects), which has those methods. It works exactly the same as using `list` object methods if you did `current = my_list; current.append(something)`

Comment: Basically you store a reference to the first Node object in the `LinkedList`, and from there you can access its methods, which allow the navigation process from Node to Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated that:

> I don't understand how the size, search and remove methods in the LinkedList class are able to call functions from the Node class via the current variable, after setting it to self.head, which seems to be contained within the scope of the LinkedList class.

You can see that in the code, initializing a LinkedList performs this line of code:

```
self.head = None
```

Since the head is set to none, the size, search, and remove methods will not run through the whole code. Rather, it will stop when the self.head == None, which is pretty much in the beginning.

For example, let's take a look at the size method.

```
def size(self):

    current = self.head
    count = 0

    while current != None:
        count += 1
        current = current.get_next()

    return count
```

In this function, current is set to self.head which is null unless you have added any nodes by calling the add() method. More on that later.

count is set equal to 0. Then a while loop begins which only runs if the current is not None. But since the current is set to self.head which is None, the while loop will not run and the function will return count which is 0. This is a correct implementation because there are currently no nodes in the linkedlist.

Now onto how you can add nodes.

The add method:

```
    def add(self, item):
        temp = Node(item)
        temp.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = temp
```

Here, the add method takes in itself and an item. The item is an object of some sort whether it be a string, integer, float, etc. Now a variable temp is created and set to a **new node** which is finally using something from the Node class. Then, temp's next node is set to head and the head is set to temp. What this does is that the linked list continuously updates the head.

Like this:

(head)
NODE1

**ADD ONE MORE NODE**

(head)
NODE2 NODE1

And so on...

Happy Coding!